# Number of contacts in segmentation list is not matching with XDB

Tags: indexing

We have migrated new contacts from external system to Mongo DB. We have ran the Sitecore Analytics Indexing using Helpfulcore.AnalyticsIndexBuilder. We have created segmentation list on EXM but data in the Mongo is not matching with data in segmentation list.
Can someone help what can be the issue? How can i check and fix if the all the contacts are not indexed from Mongo?

Comment: You may need to add some details about the version of Sitecore you are running. You may also want to look for patterns on which contacts are not getting indexed. 

For example, in v9 anonymous contacts are not indexed by default.

Comment: We are using 8.2 initial version